# Remove Content Filter

Tags: filters, content, the-content

I need help with removing the Content Filter from a Plugin:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array( &$this, 'addContentAds' ), 8 );
```

Do someone could help me please?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: what have you tried? Did you look at `remove_filter` manual? Is it a feature you don't need or are you abusing a free plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As the filter occurs within a class you must remove it by replacing `$this` (as you don't run the remove_filter on the class, $this is not available) with the name of the class where it is declared.

An example with a class called : Wecba,  you will remove it like this :

```
remove_filter('the_content', array('Wecba', 'add_Content_Ads'), 8);
```

It's nos only depends on the class name.

Hope it helps

Comment: you can use class name only, if the class is static.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 4.7 introduced `WP_Hook` class. The global variable `$wp_filter` is now an array of `WP_Hook` objects, one for every 'hook', which has filters attached to it. That makes removing filters quite easy.

You can still use `remove_filter` function, to handle filters with callback function not being declared within a class.

The code below, which you paste into `functions.php` of your current theme, will allow to remove any filter:

```
function remove_the_content_filter() {
    global $wp_filter;

    $hook = 'the_content';
    $callback = 'addContentAds';
    $priority = 8;

    if ( !is_object( $wp_filter[ $hook ] ) )
        // no filters for this $hook
        return;

    $prts = $wp_filter[ $hook ]->callbacks; // array
    $prts_cnt = count( $prts );
    $prty = $wp_filter[ $hook ]->callbacks[ $priority ]; // array

    if ( !is_array( $prty ) )
        // no filters with this $priority
        return;

    $prty_cnt = count( $prty );

    foreach ( $prty as $key => $val ) {
        if ( false != stripos( $key, $callback ) ) {
            if ( ( 1 == $prts_cnt ) && ( 1 == $prty_cnt ) ) {
                // our filter the one only
                unset( $wp_filter[ $hook ] );
                return;
            } else {
                if ( 1 == $prty_cnt ) {
                    // our filter the only one with this $priority
                    unset( $wp_filter[ $hook ]->callbacks[ $priority ] );
                    return;
                } else {
                    // there are more filters with this $priority, remove our filter
                    unset( $wp_filter[ $hook ]->callbacks[ $priority ][ $key ] );
                    return;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_the_content_filter' );
```